# Mixed parameter type in Laravel function

Tags: laravel

What means `mixed` type in Laravel documentation? Does it mean that function accepts parameters of different type?

For example, I was looking at [`bcc`](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Contracts/Mail/Mailer.html#method_bcc) function to check if I could pass array of strings as a parameter, because currently I am passing only a single string, which is not inside an array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`mixed` technically means any type of variable. It is often used when more than one type of variable can be used. In your specific case, there is a big chance you can use a single or an array.

https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mixed-typehint

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking if somewhere deeper inside documentation is written which specific types are included inside this `mixed` parameter. I guess if I try passing a number, it would throw an exception. But it works with array of strings. Will accept your answer asap

Comment: @niksrb I mean, it might be written somewhere for the specific function, or in a description for the function. In general though, `mixed` means any type and it depends on the function it is used in.